# Linting in a Ecmascript 6 Javascript (ReactJS development) with SublimeText3

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

Today I start working as a developer on a ReactJS application for my first time.

However, I'm having trouble even getting off the ground as I can't get SublimeText3 to properly recognize all the es6 syntax and JSX in this application's code.

Some relevant parameters of what I'm trying to do:

- The javascript file extensions are all .jsx so keep that in mind
- I'm trying to use [SublimeLinter-jsxhint](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jsxhint) since SublimeLinter is my favorite linter out there.

What I've tried so far....

1. Installed SublimeLinter-jsxhint
2. Followed the SublimeLinter-jsxhint instructions to install jsxhint globally `npm install -g jsxhint`
3. Installed 'Babel' Package, also called [babel-sublime](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime)
4. Restarted my computer and Sublime

According to SublimeLinter-jsxhint docs that is all the steps I'm supposed to be required for the linter to work.... however errors are thrown all over my code with ES6 only syntax.

**AFTER MORE RESEARCH**

The step it looks like I might be messing up on is this:

> Linter configuration
>
> In order for `jsxhint` to be executed by SublimeLinter, you must ensure that its path is available to SublimeLinter. Before going any further, please read and follow the steps in [“Finding a linter executable”](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#finding-a-linter-executable) through “Validating your PATH” in the documentation.
>
> Once `jsxhint` is installed and configured, you can proceed to install the SublimeLinter-jsxhint plugin if it is not yet installed.

So perhaps `jsxhint` cannot be executed by SublimeLinter because its path is unavailable to SublimeLinter.

How should I do to fix this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'd say the majority of people doing ES6 and JSX using ESLint, is that something you've explored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps work for me on Windows:

1. Install your linter globally: `npm install -g jsxhint` (or ESLint; I personally use ESLint, but I've never used JSXHint so I can't speak to which one is better).
2. Check where NPM installs global packages: `npm root -g`; the default should be `C:\Users\you\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`
3. Check the parent path (`C:\Users\you\AppData\Roaming\npm`). You should have `jsxhint.cmd` there.
4. Add `C:\Users\you\AppData\Roaming\npm` to your PATH variable.
5. You should be able to type `jsxhint` into a console now, and it will be recognized. That should also mean that SublimeLinter has access.